# How to best work with collection updates in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having an issue with keeping track of collection state updates in ReactJS

I have model called Ticket

```
export default class Ticket {
    numbers?: number[];

    constructor(numbers?: number[]) {
        if (numbers == undefined) {
            numbers = []
        }
        this.numbers = numbers
    }
}
```

Now in my Home Component I have the following

```
const [tickets, setTickets] = useState<Ticket[]>([]);
const [activeTicket, setActiveTicket] = useState<Ticket>(new Ticket());
```

Now, I have a function as below

```
const addMoreTickets = () => {
        let newTicket = new Ticket();
        setTickets([...tickets, newTicket]);
        setActiveTicket(tickets[tickets.length-1]); //This doesn't work, it still holds the old ticket instead of the newly added ticket

    }
```

Is there a work around to this?

Comment: setState is `async` so `tickets.length` returns the length of array before you push your new `Ticket`. Why don't you just use `setActiveTicket(newTicket)`?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and suggestion. I have however resorted to useEffect() to always get the latest update.